# Error "Invalid Intent Vocabulary" from App Store when trying to submit an app with Siri extension

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store, siri

My app is using a Siri extension with *custom* Siri intents, which is a new feature for Xcode 10 / iOS 12. I design my custom Siri intents in a `.intentdefinition` file (included for both app and extension targets).

My *custom* (not system) Siri intents are declared within the "Do" category.

[image]

A Siri intent also requires a `AppIntentVocabulary.plist` file with example phrases in it https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/registering_custom_vocabulary_with_sirikit

I've got my `AppIntentVocabulary.plist` included for the app target only. It looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>IntentPhrases</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>IntentName</key>
            <string>MyIntentName1</string>
            <key>IntentExamples</key>
            <array>
                <string>Do stuff with foo</string>
                <string>Do stuff with fu</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>IntentName</key>
            <string>MyIntentName2</string>
            <key>IntentExamples</key>
            <array>
                <string>Do other stuff</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>ParameterVocabularies</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>ParameterNames</key>
            <array>
                <string>MyIntentName1.someParam</string>
            </array>
            <key>ParameterVocabulary</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>VocabularyItemIdentifier</key>
                    <string>paramName</string>
                    <key>VocabularyItemSynonyms</key>
                    <array>
                        <dict>
                            <key>VocabularyItemPhrase</key>
                            <string>foo</string>
                            <key>VocabularyItemPronunciation</key>
                            <string>fu</string>
                            <key>VocabularyItemExamples</key>
                            <array>
                                <string>Do stuff with foo</string>
                            </array>
                        </dict>
                        <dict>
                            <key>VocabularyItemPhrase</key>
                            <string>bar</string>
                            <key>VocabularyItemPronunciation</key>
                            <string>bur</string>
                            <key>VocabularyItemExamples</key>
                            <array>
                                <string>Do stuff with bar</string>
                            </array>
                        </dict>
                    </array>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

It builds fine and works ok too. But when I'm trying to submit it to App Store, I get:

> [Transporter Error Output]: ERROR ITMS-90624: "Invalid Intent
>   Vocabulary. The AppIntentVocabulary.plist file in the
>   Payload/AppName.app/en.lproj folder can't contain the intent name
>   "MyIntentName1"."

And there are subsequent error messages repeating for every `.lproj` folder.

If it helps, my app is localized for 14 languages, the project is not using base localization.

Comment: Well I’m not sure, but can you try replacing MyIntentName1.someParam with MyIntentName1 only and try again

Comment: It should be the key path @iOS_Developer

Comment: @Desmond did u get the solution?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue when not using Base Localization. As stated from the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/registering_custom_vocabulary_with_sirikit):

> Place your AppIntentVocabulary.plist file in the language-specific
>   (.lproj) directory of your iOS app that corresponds to your base
>   development language.

Not using Base localization can create this kind of problems especially with key names, as it needs a neutral name (using the same English wording works as well) to link against all the localized keys.

Answer (score 2):

For the moment, you can only define custom vocabulary on a few specific types of intents: see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/registering_custom_vocabulary_with_sirikit) under "Register User-Specific Vocabulary" for a list, but it's things like ride sharing, notes, workouts etc. In other words, not your custom intents (that you might want to expose to iOS 12's Siri shortcuts - that's not available... yet).

And the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/registering_custom_vocabulary_with_sirikit/global_vocabulary_reference/intent_phrases) say you need to specify one of those intents as the `Intent name` in the plist. Likewise, the parameter names need to be specific parameters of just those permitted intents. So I'm guessing that's why you're getting errors on uploading to the App Store - it's checking to see if Siri supports custom vocabulary for "MyIntentName1". Not sure why it's working locally for you, or why this isn't a check built into Xcode. ‍♀️

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I however can't find the exact place in the docs where it says that we should not use `AppIntentVocabulary.plist` with custom intents created with `.intentdefinition` files. "Register User-Specific Vocabulary" that you are referring to is bit different, it's a way to register user-specific vocabulary terms at runtime as opposed to compile-time `AppIntentVocabulary.plist`.

Comment: The docs make a distinction between global and user-specific terms but only list acceptable categories for user-specific terms. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/registering_custom_vocabulary_with_sirikit says: "Unlike the global terms, which you declare in your app bundle, you declare user-specific terms at runtime from your iOS app. The terms you declare must belong to one of the following categories." And then go the limited number of categories

Comment: You're right, me neither! - Actually further up https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/registering_custom_vocabulary_with_sirikit when talking about the plist option, it's actually even more restrictive and states "You may specify custom vocabulary terms for ride options and workout names." Is it that you can and should include intent phrases for any custom intents you provide ("The IntentPhrases key contains example phrases for invoking your services. Always include this key."), but parameter names for custom intents are a no-go, and that's what's giving you the error?

Comment: I already tried submitting without parameters, no params in the custom intent and no params in `AppIntentVocabulary.plist`, but got the same error from App Store as before.

Comment: Did you see this? Possible testflight issue? https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/108226

Comment: Yes, I have seen that. It didn't explain much.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if it was a clue that a combination of xcode + testflight was at fault. I still think that this is something that Apple doesn't currently support, but I hope you get to the bottom of it! Good luck :)

Comment: I just encountered the same problem and found this answer by an Apple employee on the [Apple Dev forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/131455): "Custom intents should not include a AppIntentVocabulary.plist file in the app. Those phrases are not used to trigger your intent, only the phrase associated with the shortcut is."